# Add attributes to textbox using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am using asp.net MVC.

I have control like

`<%= Html.TextBox("username") %>`

I want lost focus event to that control.

So code like

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#username").Attributes.Add("onblur", "alert('losing focus');");
});
```

but it is not working,

Ultimate goal is to check password & confirm password matches

help me!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to use C# code in jQuery?

The easiest way to bind an event to onblur in jQuery is:

```
$("#username").blur(function() { alert('losing focus'); });
```

More information on blur() is available at http://docs.jquery.com/Events/blur

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#username").blur(function() {
    alert('byebye focus');
  });
});
```

http://docs.jquery.com/Events/blur

Answer (score 1):

You can try attach to this event with another way, like this:

```
$("#username").bind("blur", function(e){
  alert('hello');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe your jQuery syntax is wrong,

You want to bind an event, "onBlur" that fires the alert, so try

```
$("#username").blur(function(){
  alert("loosing focus");
});
```

-- update, looks like some one answered this as I was answering